# How to prevent certain internal routes from being accessed by the user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site with a lot of routes.

Some routes, e.g. `/sector-overview` are to a specific page that I want the user to see.

Other routes, e.g. `/sectoroverview` are to an an action that ultimately renders a partial which is included on the homepage.

the second route is only meant to be internal to the application, but if the user types that into their address bar (it's an easy mistake to make), the system sees that as a valid request and it'll return the HTML partial.

I *could* rename the second route to something like `/internal-sectoroverview`, but this isn't really fixing the problem, just hiding it.

Is there any way for me to prevent the request from being processed if the user types this? What's the best way for me to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can block the route by using [route constraints](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx). However, in your case I would decorate your internal Action with `[ChildActionOnly]` like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    return View();
}
```

By doing this, the action will be only rendered when using `@Html.Action` or `@Html.RenderAction`. If you try to access it through a browser, you'll get an error.

**UPDATE**

To return a 404 instead of an error you can override the `OnException` method on the controller and handle it there. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    //check if filterContext.Exception was thrown by child action only (maybe by text)
    filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
}
```

Comment: Regarding that error, what's the best way to catch that and issue a 404 instead?

Comment: See my update, that's an option, but I'm not sure if it's the best one. by the way, I think you can also do it on Global.asax if you find it better

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you should resolve the problem of the partial not being called using the attribute [ChildActionOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx).just for reference if you don't want that a method in your action can be called at all use the [NonActionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute.aspx)

Comment: If you tag the method using `[NonAction]` you'll end up with an action that does NOT render AT ALL.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote. "If you DON'T want that a method can be called"

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem issue that people finding this might also need - I want to return 404 if a certain criteria is met from a function that returns a PartialViewResult.  The solution for me was

```
public PartialViewResult MyFunction()
{
   if( criteria ) {
      Response.StatusCode = 404;
      return null;
   }
}
```