# Is it possible to deny access via URL to a PartialViewResult action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, action

I'm trying to deny access to an action returning `PartialViewResult`; but it seems to be impossible. If I tag the action method with `NonAction` attribute, the page won't render and if I don't, it's possible to get that partial view using a URL.
Suppose I have this in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<section role="navigation">
    @Html.Partial("PageParts/Sidebar")
    @RenderSection("SidebarContents", required: false)
</section>
```

and this is `PageParts/Sidebar.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Partial("PageParts/Sidebar/Userinfo")
@{Html.RenderAction("getNavigation", "PageSemantics");}
```

and this is `PageSemanticsController.cs`:

```
public class PageSemanticsController : Controller {

    public PartialViewResult getNavigation() {
        NavigationModel nm = new NavigationModel();
        return PartialView("PageParts/Sidebar/Navigation", nm);
    }
}
```

and finally this is `~/Views/Shared/PageParts/Sidebar/Navigation.cshtml`:

```
@model NavigationModel
<nav id="main-nav">
    [... Some code to create Navigation ...]
</nav>
```

---

This setup works fine, except `~/PageSemantics/getNavigation` is accessible via URL.
Is there any way to deny access to `getNavigation` action via URL while keeping this setup working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to put attribute

```
[ChildActionOnly]
```

on your `getNavigation()` method

Comment: Thanks, this returns a message like `the action 'getnavigation' is accessible only by a child request.`  
Is it possible to return a 404 ?

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888121/how-to-prevent-certain-internal-routes-from-being-accessed-by-the-user